# Isolation level of transaction and locked table

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I have a c# program in which i created a transaction with isolation level of READ UNCOMMITTED. During the execution of this program I cannot view the table under midification (and really any other table in the database) using the server explorer of Visual Studio. Is it normal? The worst is that no other thread can access to the table during the activity of this transaction.

Answer (score 0):

By under modification, is DDL (i.e. `CREATE`, `ALTER`, `DROP`) being performed on this table?  Schema modification (`Sch-M`) locks are placed on objects used in DDL operations and this will prevent other transactions from accessing the objects once the `Sch-M` locks are taken, including those using either the `READUNCOMMITTED` isolation level or the `NOLOCK` hint.